# How can I combine two rows given a condition using google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I need to combine two rows based on the first column:

[image]

If the column "A" is the same, the formula needs to combine the rows so that we obtain this:
[image]

If the upper row is FALSE, and the lower row is FALSE we obtain FALSE. In any other case, we obtain TRUE.

How can I make this?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give a try to the following formula and let us know your feedback in comment.

```
=LET(x,
UNIQUE(A2:A7),
y,MAP(x,LAMBDA(cli,OR(FILTER(B2:B,A2:A=cli)))),
z,MAP(x,LAMBDA(ews,OR(FILTER(C2:C,A2:A=ews)))),
HSTACK(x,y,z))
```

[image]